# CUDA 2D Kernel Coalesced Memory

Tags: cuda

If I launch a 2D kernel in which each thread operates on a single element of a 2D array, which way of accessing the element is coalesced? Is it array[x][y] or array[y][x]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `x = threadIdx.x` and `y = threadIdx.y` then

```
array[y][x]
```

will be coalesced but

```
array[x][y]
```

not. The reason is that C uses [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), i.e. the last index is the fastest running one so that `array[y][x]` and `array[y][x+1]` go to adjacent locations in memory. And threads within CUDA blocks are arranged so that `threadIdx.x` runs fastest, then y and finally z.

Comment: Just adding this is also true for non CUDA code, using cache coherence http://supercomputingblog.com/optimization/taking-advantage-of-cache-coherence-in-your-programs/